# Not able to get the expected Assert statement in my test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

[image][image]My Assert Statement is failing in the below logic and i am not able to get the proper expected value ,

Please find the Codes in the Screenshots.

[image: Test1]

Logic:

```
public static void wmgRemoveOldGroupQueue(Map<Id,case> newMap,Map<Id,Case> oldMap){

string WmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SobjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
for(case o: newMap.Values()){
   if(o.RecordTypeId ==  WmgRecordTypeId && !((String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005') && (o.ownerId != oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId)){
               o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c='';
  }
 }
}
```

test Class :

```
static testMethod void wmgRemoveOldQueueTest(){
 //setup

user thisUser = [select Id FROM user where ID = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
string WmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SobjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
string assertMessage = 'Accepted From Queue did not clear out';
QueueSobject q = [Select QueueId,Queue.Name From  QueueSobject Where SobjectType = 'Case' and Queue.Name = 'WMG Ops - Licensing' limit 1];

Case c = new Case();
c.ownerId = q.QueueId;
c.RecordTypeId =  WmgRecordTypeId;
insert c;

c = [SELECT OwnerId, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, RecordTypeId FROM Case WHERE Id = c.Id];
c.ownerId = thisUser.Id;
update c;

c = [SELECT OwnerId, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, RecordTypeId FROM Case WHERE Id = c.Id];
c.ownerId = q.QueueId;
c.RecordTypeId =  WmgRecordTypeId;
update c;

///This is Failing
System.assertEquals(null,[SELECT ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case Where Id=:c.Id].ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, assertMsg);
```

Comment: Instead of taking screenshots of your code, it's preferred to have code entered here as text. Text is preferred because it can be formatted and copied (which helps other people reproduce your issue). Code screenshots tend to be somewhere between hard and impossible to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your unit test is failing because the owner ID did not change. You assigned it to the queue too early:

```
Case c = new Case();
c.ownerId = q.QueueId;
c.RecordTypeId =  WmgRecordTypeId;
insert c;
```

Instead, allow the owner ID to be the current user on insert:

```
Case c = new Case();
// c.ownerId = q.QueueId; // Remove this line
c.RecordTypeId =  WmgRecordTypeId;
insert c;
```

Your assertion should then pass.