# Trigger.newMap and Trigger.oldMap not able to pass the correct values in the test Class!

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, code-coverage, code

I have a scenario to cover in the Test Class Whenever Case is assign to queue from User : particular field must get blank:

```
 public static void wmgRemoveOldGroupQueue(Map<Id,Case> newMap, Map<Id,Case> oldMap){

    String wmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();

    for (Case o : newMap.values()) {

        System.debug('newMap.valuesafter o'+newMap.values());
        system.debug('o.OwnerId == '+newMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId+' oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId =='+oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId);
        system.debug('o.RecordTypeId '+o.RecordTypeId+ 'wmgRecordTypeId'+wmgRecordTypeId);
        System.debug('o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c' +o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c);
        System.debug('@@ : '+!((String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005'));
        System.debug('@@1 : '+((String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005'));

        if (o.RecordTypeId == wmgRecordTypeId && !((String)o.OwnerId).startsWith('005') &&
            (o.OwnerId != oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId)) {
            o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = '';


        }
        system.debug('o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c' +o.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c);

    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
  static testMethod void wmgRemoveOldQueueTest() {        
    //setup 
    User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
    String wmgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
    String assertMsg = 'Accepted From Queue could not clear out';        
    //QueueSobject q = [SELECT QueueId, Queue.Name FROM QueueSobject WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' and Queue.Name = 'WMG Ops - Licensing' LIMIT 1];

    Case c = new Case();
    //c.OwnerId = thisUser.Id;
    c.RecordTypeId = wmgRecordTypeId;
    c.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c = 'Test';
    insert c;
    System.debug('Owner id at insert is '+c.OwnerId);

    System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId())){
     Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];

     User u = new User(Alias = 'staudt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='5Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standardusedd4r@testorg.com');

   insert u;
        c.OwnerId=u.Id;
    update c;
    }



   Group testGroup = new Group(Name='test group', Type='Queue');
   insert testGroup;

   System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()))
```

{
    QueuesObject q = new QueueSObject(QueueID = testGroup.id, SObjectType = 'Case');
    insert q;
   }

```
    //c = [SELECT OwnerId, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, RecordTypeId FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];
    //c.OwnerId = thisUser.Id;
    //update c;
    //System.assertEquals(Test, [SELECT ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id].ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, 'Failed');
    //system.assertEquals(c.OwnerId, thisUser.Id, 'Failed2');


    //c.RecordTypeId = wmgRecordTypeId;
    //system.assert(((String)c.OwnerId).startsWith('00G'), 'Owner issue');

    //system.assert(((String)c.OwnerId).startsWith('00G'), 'Owner issue');


    case newCase = [SELECT id, Ownerid, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];
    newCase.OwnerId=testGroup.Id;
    //QueueSobject q1 = [SELECT QueueId, Queue.Name FROM QueueSobject WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' and QueueID=testGroup.Id LIMIT 1];
    test.startTest();
     update newCase;
     System.debug('TestGroup id'+testGroup.Id);

    //update newCase(id=c.Id,OwnerId = testGroup.Id);
    test.stopTest();
    system.debug('newCase.OwnerId1 =='+newCase.OwnerId);

    case r = [SELECT id, Ownerid, ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.Id];
    system.debug('r Owner Id =='+r.OwnerId);

    system.debug('r ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c =='+r.ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c);
    System.assertEquals('',[SELECT ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case Where Id=:r.Id].ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c, assertMsg);
    System.debug('fff'+[SELECT ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c FROM Case Where Id=:r.Id].ANN_Accepted_From_Queue__c);

}
```

In My Trigger logic the Debug Statement : 
system.debug('o.OwnerId == '+newMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId+' oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId =='+oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId);

Values==> 17:32:14:242 USER_DEBUG [733]|DEBUG|o.OwnerId == 00518000003xRhcAAE oldMap.get(o.Id).OwnerId ==00518000003xRhcAAE

not able to pass the corrected values in Trigger.newMap:

and in the test class after update :
system.debug('r Owner Id =='+r.OwnerId);
Value:==>r Owner Id ==00G18000002gdy9EAA

Successfully changed to Queue:

Please let me know if anyway to pass this unit test
Still my Field ANN_* not getting blank, From UI working perfectly:

Comment: Please **stop creating duplicate accounts**.

Comment: Not able to get the correct answer

Comment: That's an indication that your questions are either not clear enough, or are lacking detail. Creating duplicate accounts is just going to annoy people, which makes the chances of getting an answer even lower.

Comment: You also have never explained why sfdcfox's answer on one of the previous iterations of this question ( https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275035/not-able-to-get-the-expected-assert-statement-in-my-test-class ) is insufficient.

Comment: okay !!! but same this is working perfectly from UI we are struggle to make in Test Class! Please remove ( salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275035/… )  this question as new one has correct explanation

Comment: You may [edit] your previous question(s) to clarify them. If you no longer have access to your previous account, you need to use the **Contact Us** link at the bottom of the page to reach out to Stack Exchange for assistance merging and accessing your accounts.

Comment: Done apology for duplicate question!!